# Does wrapping a query in SELECT protect you completely in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, security

Given a client library that can only execute one statement in a batch, if you run

```
query.exec_sql("SELECT * FROM (" + sql + ")")
```

Are there any vectors where `sql` can run anything but a `SELECT` ?

Are there any other ways to temporarily de-elevate a connection so it can only perform SELECT?

Note: It looks like SET ROLE solves this problem, but the the issue I have is that I am unable to create a role upfront in an easy way.

Comment: What is the client and driver?

Comment: You should be using a user with proper permissions GRANTed for that, and not such a “workaround”.

Answer (score 1):

While you can put data-modifying statements in queries by embedding `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements in [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html), they're only allowed at the top level, so that's not an issue.

You can, however, invoke a function, which could contain just about anything. Even if you ran this in a read-only transaction, a function could potentially elevate it to read-write.

But the solution is simple: If you don't want to allow the caller to do something, don't give them permission to do it. Create a user with only the [`GRANTs`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-grant.html) they need, and you can execute `sql` as-is.

Without the ability to define permissions, the closest you're going to get is probably a [read-only transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-set-transaction.html) and/or an explicit rollback after the query, but there will still be holes you can't plug (e.g. you can't roll back a [`setval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html) call).

Comment: I understand this, my issue is that it complicates provisioning cause now I am stuck provisioning two accounts. wrapping in a transaction with a rollback combined with the above should guarantee safety then no?

Comment: I guess sort of, since a function could possible issue a commit an begin a new transaction ...

Comment: I don't think you can control transactions from within a function. But you can do far worse than that... e.g. `pg_terminate_backend()` calls to kick everyone off the server, or `COPY` commands to replace the Postgres binaries...

Comment: So there is no way to de-elevate permissions on a connection short of creating a new user / role?

Comment: Permissions are *defined* through roles. You can restrict permissions, but you need a restricted role to switch to.

Comment: which needs to be defined by a user that has permission to define a role, so I am in a bit of a catch 22 ... I have too many permissions, but not enough to create a new role that has the permissions I need.

Comment: I see, I can do stuff with roles http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/role-membership.html

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  permission denied to create role .... that would be easy, cause then I could just SET ROLE before executing.

Answer (score 0):

If the `sql` string came from a third party then it can be used to SQL injection. I'm not sure if that is what you are asking because it is too basic for a 56k points user to ask. Sorry if that is not the case. The string could be:

```
some_table; insert into user_table (user_id, admin_privilege) values (1, true);
```

Comment: He said assuming it's a single statement. If your client is preparing its queries, I believe this is a safe assumption in Postgres.

Comment: It could even be a subquery using a DELETE and RETURNING.... The result will be the last thing you see from the deleted records :-(

Comment: @FrankHeikens have you tested that `select * from (delete from t returning *) q` this is a syntax error

Comment: @SamSaffron: You're right, my mistake. You must use a CTE to use a DELETE in this type of attack. That doesn't work in this case, the DELETE must be at the top level.